# How to specify Berlin districts using googlevis in R?

Tags: r, googlevis

I have the problem that I can't figure out how to specify the districts of Berlin in order to add the value of the population to it. The R code looks like this:

```
GeoBerlin_bev <-
  gvisGeoChart(data_bev,
               locationvar = 'Bezirk',
               colorvar = 'Bevoelkerung',
               options = list(region = "DE", 
                              displayMode="regions",
                              resolution = 'provinces',
                              showLegend = TRUE,
                              width=600, height=400))`
```

The content of the column `Bezirk` looks like this: `Charlottenburg-Wilmersdorf, Berlin`. The content of the column `Bevoelkerung` looks like this: `142.1`.

I would like the chart to show Berlin, the districts and the number of the population.